# Delete a row from a text file with Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file where each line starts with a number. The user can delete a row by typing in the number of the row the user would like to delete.

The issue I'm having is setting the mode for opening it. When I use `a+`, the original content is still there. However, tacked onto the end of the file are the lines that I want to keep. On the other hand, when I use `w+`, the entire file is deleted. I'm sure there is a better way than opening it with `w+` mode, deleting everything, and then re-opening it and appending the lines.

```
 def DeleteToDo(self):
    print "Which Item Do You Want To Delete?"
    DeleteItem = raw_input(">") #select a line number to delete
    print "Are You Sure You Want To Delete Number" + DeleteItem + "(y/n)"
    VerifyDelete = str.lower(raw_input(">"))
    if VerifyDelete == "y":
        FILE = open(ToDo.filename,"a+") #open the file (tried w+ as well, entire file is deleted)
        FileLines = FILE.readlines() #read and display the lines
        for line in FileLines:
            FILE.truncate()
            if line[0:1] != DeleteItem: #if the number (first character) of the current line doesn't equal the number to be deleted, re-write that line
                FILE.write(line)
    else:
        print "Nothing Deleted"
```

This is what a typical file may look like

```
1. info here
2. more stuff here
3. even more stuff here
```

Comment: "I'm sure there's a better way than opening it with w+ mode, deleting everything, then re-opening it and appending the lines." **No.**

Comment: So, there's no way to delete the contents of a file in a+ mode?

Comment: That could get inconvenient as the number of rows becomes large. If you're not attached to text files as storage, perhaps a database would be a better data storage solution?

Comment: The best you can do is truncate the file to before the start of the line you want to delete, and only write out the lines after. And even than that probably won't make things faster if you don't have a quick way of figuring out which byte that is. (Like an index of some sort.)

Comment: This is just for my personal use. I suppose a database could be used, but I figured keeping it simple would be good for now.

Comment: How big of a file are we talking about? It is strictly line oriented?

Comment: In fact, a major influence on the design of database systems is that they have to get around the fact that filesystems can't do what you ask. (And thus are able to do everything with updates change / replace fixed-size records.)

Comment: @millimoose I updated my code above for truncating, but it doesn't seem to work. The code is still appended to the end. When I use w+ it gets deleted entirely just like before.

Comment: @user1104854 [The documentation for `truncate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truncate#file.truncate) states: "If the optional size argument is present, the file is truncated to that size. The size defaults to the current position." Since `readlines()` reads everything in the file, the current position would presumably be the end of the file. As I said, you need to truncate *before* the line you're deleting, then write out all the lines *after*.

Comment: The position will also have to be the number of bytes that make up the  previous lines as originally read, which might be tricky to determine if you can't assume ASCII or another fixed-width encoding. (This isn't a trivial optimization, and it's probably not really worth the effort trying to get the bookkeeping necessary to support Unicode right.)

Comment: @millimoose I changed the position of the truncate command and it's still doing the same thing. Changing mode to a+ or r+ just appends, w+ erases everything.

Comment: @user1104854 I think you severely misunderstand what "position" means in the context. It's part of the internal state of the file object, not the location of the command in the source file. I'd recommend [brushing up on how POSIX file I/O works](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Overview.html#I_002fO-Overview).

Comment: @millimoose when I set truncate to 0 I get a bunch of NULL spaces at the beginning of my file.

Comment: @user1104854 Maybe this is a hint that you should stop flailing about and either learn file IO in-depth, or implement this in the way you know works. My guess is the reason why that happens is that you truncate the file, but the `position` remains where it was, at the end. (As the documentation for `truncate()` says.)

Comment: @millimoose thanks for the tip. You were right about it not being in the correct position. I didn't realize the seek() function existed. It took me a bit to find it because I was looking at the C versions you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def DeleteToDo():
    print ("Which Item Do You Want To Delete?")
    DeleteItem = raw_input(">") #select a line number to delete
    print ("Are You Sure You Want To Delete Number" + DeleteItem + "(y/n)")
    DeleteItem=int(DeleteItem) 
    VerifyDelete = str.lower(raw_input(">"))
    if VerifyDelete == "y":
        FILE = open('data.txt',"r") #open the file (tried w+ as well, entire file is deleted)
        lines=[x.strip() for x in FILE if int(x[:x.index('.')])!=DeleteItem] #read all the lines first except the line which matches the line number to be deleted
        FILE.close()
        FILE = open('data.txt',"w")#open the file again
        for x in lines:FILE.write(x+'\n')    #write the data to the file

    else:
        print ("Nothing Deleted")
DeleteToDo()
```

Comment: Awesome, this works great after a small tweak (changed DeleteItem to string). Can you please explain the lines = [x.strip....] statement? I looked up strip and I see that it removes leading characters, but what exactly is the last part of that doing? (x[:x.index.....

Comment: `strip()` removes trailing and leading whitespaces, `x[:x.index('.')]` returns a substring from the current line upto th first `.` character, which is the number, and if the integer of that subtstring is equal to
`DeleteItem` then that line is skipped.

Comment: `strip()` is performed in the end, if a line satisfies that `if` condition then only it is stripped.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file for writing, you clobber the file (delete its current contents and start a new file).  You can find this out by reading documentation for the `open()` command.

When you open a file for appending, you do not clobber the file.  But how can you delete just one line?  A file is a sequence of bytes stored on a storage device; there is no way for you to delete one line and have all the other lines automatically "slide down" into new positions on the storage device.

(If your data was stored in a database, you could actually delete just one "row" from the database; but a file is not a database.)

So, the traditional way to solve this: you read from the original file, and you copy it to a new output file.  As you copy, you perform any desired edits; for example, you can delete a line simply by not copying that one line; or you can insert a line by writing it in the new file.

Then, once you have successfully written the new file, and successfully closed it, if there is no error, you go ahead and rename the new file back to the same name as the old file (which clobbers the old file).

In Python, your code should be something like this:

```
import os

# "num_to_delete" was specified by the user earlier.

# I'm assuming that the number to delete is set off from
# the rest of the line with a space.

s_to_delete = str(num_to_delete) + ' '
def want_input_line(line):
    return not line.startswith(s_to_delete)

in_fname = "original_input_filename.txt"
out_fname = "temporary_filename.txt"

with open(in_fname) as in_f, open(out_fname, "w") as out_f:
    for line in in_f:
        if want_input_line(line):
            out_f.write(line)

os.rename(out_fname, in_fname)
```

Note that if you happen to have a file called `temporary_filename.txt` it will be clobbered by this code.  Really we don't care what the filename is, and we can ask Python to make up some unique filename for us, using the `tempfile` module.

Any recent version of Python will let you use multiple statements in a single `with` statement, but if you happen to be using Python 2.6 or something you can nest two `with` statements to get the same effect:

```
with open(in_fname) as in_f:
    with open(out_fname, "w") as out_f:
        for line in in_f:
            ... # do the rest of the code
```

Also, note that I did *not* use the `.readlines()` method to get the input lines, because `.readlines()` reads the entire contents of the file into memory, all at once, and if the file is very large this will be slow or might not even work.  You can simply write a `for` loop using the "file object" you get back from `open()`; this will give you one line at a time, and your program will work with even really large files.

EDIT: Note that my answer is assuming that you just want to do one editing step.  As @jdi noted in comments for another answer, if you want to allow for "interactive" editing where the user can delete multiple lines, or insert lines, or whatever, then the easiest way is in fact to read all the lines into memory using `.readlines()`, insert/delete/update/whatever on the resulting list, and then only write out the list to a file a single time when editing is all done.

Comment: thanks for the writeup! I do have it working using the current method above, but I'll give yours a shot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing out all lines one by one to the file, delete the line from memory (to which you read the file using readlines()) and then write the memory back to disk in one shot. That way you will get the result you want, and you won't have to clog the I/O.

Comment: And maybe even keep the file structure in memory while you are in "edit" mode, instead of opening it again every time for a new line change.

Comment: "Clog the I/O"? (It's just that this sounds like something buffering would take care of one way or the other.)

Comment: That depends on how large the text files are. For huge files, it may be (programatically) simpler to read and write the files line-by-line and (speed-wise) faster if you read/write them in chunks

Comment: @bos can you please give me an example of what you're talking about. I'm new to python and I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't recommend using the `.readlines()` method function.  This reads the entire file into memory, which will be a problem if the file is very large.  See my answer for how to write a `for` loop that just reads one line at a time.

Comment: @steveha: I think that if the file is big enough that reading it all at once would cause problems, then anything other than a database would be a bad choice.

Comment: @Amr, my attitude is: if there are two ways to do something, and one of the two always works and is less characters to type as well, why not use the one that always works?  If you ever write a Python program that sifts through log files, your program may end up sifting a 5 GB log file someday.  If you are going to just look at one line at a time anyway, why call `.readlines()` and slurp the whole file at once?

Comment: @jdi, I agree that if multiple editing steps are required, and the files are reasonably small, the best thing to do is slurp the file using `.readlines()`, insert and delete stuff from the list of lines, and then write the whole list of lines in one go.  The description of the problem made me think this was a one-time filtering operation, but if it might be interactive, then yeah defer the writing until the editing is all done.

Comment: @steveha: yea thats the only reason I made that suggestion to keep it in memory. The OP's example seems to suggest an interactive modification to lines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for the lines numbers in your file, you can do something like this:

```
def DeleteToDo(self):
    print "Which Item Do You Want To Delete?"
    DeleteItem = int(raw_input(">")) - 1
    print "Are You Sure You Want To Delete Number" + str(DeleteItem) + "(y/n)"
    VerifyDelete = str.lower(raw_input(">"))
    if VerifyDelete == "y":
        with open(ToDo.filename,"r") as f:
            lines = ''.join([a for i,a in enumerate(f) if i != DeleteItem])

        with open(ToDo.filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(lines)
    else:
        print "Nothing Deleted"
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're doing, but I think there are a couple minor errors. First, why are you subtracting 1 from DeleteItem? Also, I believe it has to be a string so it can be concatenated in the next statement (printing). I'd really appreciate your thoughts because I'd like to get this working as well. Just trying to get better with Python.

Comment: @user1104854: I edited to fix the string issue, and the -1 is because you normally would specify the line you want to delete starting from 1 not 0, but usually in programming indexes start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could `mmap` the file... after haven read the suitable documentation...

Comment: ...and then what?  A memory-mapped file doesn't have database-like semantics.  You could easily overwrite bytes, but to delete bytes and shift all the other bytes down would still be nontrivial.