# Deleting line that startswith in txt file?

Tags: python, line

I have text file like this:

```
test:Player:232.746860697:76.0:206.635144909
b2:Player2:245.330907228:77.0:207.785677928
b3:Player4:236.52764454:76.0:203.95246227
b45:Player33:240.496564206:77.0:205.574781979
```

I want to delete line that starts with i.e. test:Player, I already made this, but I don't know how to delete that line? Here's my code so far:

```
pluginlokacija2 = os.path.realpath("%s/plugins"%os.getcwd())
textfile = open("%s/CreativePoints/Data/plotovi.txt"%pluginlokacija2, 'r')
for line in textfile.readlines():  
    if line.startswith("%s:%s"%(args[1], sender.getName())):
        #delete that line, how?
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: U can not delete. Copy the content of a file line by line and write them back by removing unwanted lines.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249966/deleting-row-from-text-file-with-python

Comment: @Arvind I already saw that but I don't understand it. Im still beginner @ python, is there any way you can explain it to me by answering with some code examples? Thank you.

Comment: @Arvind Just tried that, it's not working. I explained it in comment below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Filter unwanted lines
a = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("%s:%s"%(args[1], sender.getName())), \
            textfile.readlines())

# Write filtered lines to file 
textfile.seek(0)
textfile.truncate()
textfile.writelines(list(x.strip() for x in a))
textfile.close()
```

And don't forget to open the file as readable and writable (`r+` instead of `r`).

To make writes reliable put all operations on file into context manager:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse 
with open('/home/reserve/Desktop/s.txt', 'r+') as f:
    b = ifilterfalse(lambda x: x.startswith("%s:%s"%(args[1],sender.getName())),\
                    f.readlines())
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(list(x.strip() for x in b))
```

Comment: It's not working, line is not being removed, it prints out my checker as it's done, but actually file is not being changed.

Comment: Same problem again. I opened file as r+ :(

Comment: Now it deletes everything from file :o

Comment: It works now. But is there any way I can stop it from making free line while entering new line. http://pastebin.com/fxGVcUv4 There is code, it should be no line between these two lines, since it produces me errors..

Comment: How do I strip them? Also I'm not sure when to strip them? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get this when trying to import this: ImportError: cannot import name filterfalse

Comment: Now if I try to delete second of 3 lines, it deletes third one too, so just first one remains... (using second example)

Comment: but both of them have this problem, if I try to delete second line, it deletes every line after (3,4,5,6,7...), just first one remains undeleted...

Comment: Just saw it's stacking all previous lines in one line, that's the problem. Is there any way to make it as it was? Line below line, not in one row... http://pastebin.com/mTeSLXx3

Answer (score 1):

```
    f = open("a.txt","r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    f = open("a.txt","w")

    for line in lines:
      if not line.startswith('test:Player'):
        f.write(line)
        print(line)
    f.close()
```

Hope this helps. Modify according to your requirements.