# Delete a row from a CSV where input matches in column

Tags: python, csv, file-io

How would I go about deleting a key and the keys values from a txt file? For example if the user wants to delete a person called Sarah from this file:

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@example.com,01269 512355, 1, 0, 0, 0,
Sarah,Brown,S.brown@example.com,01866 522555, 1, 0,  0, 0,
…
```

Currently I have the following:

```python
L = open("players.txt","r+")

delete_name1 = raw_input ("Enter the first name of the person you wish to delete: ")
for line in L:
    s = line.strip()
    string = s.split(",")
    if delete_name1 == string[0]:
        del string[:8] # Doesn't work
        print delete_name1 + " has been deleted."
L.close() # Closes the file to free us usage space.
```

The code is accepted but it doesn't change the txt file. I feel like I have to write the updated information back into the txt file but I don't know how to do this.

```
Please select an option: 2
Enter the first name of the person you wish to delete: Sarah
Sarah has been deleted
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Provide your current attempts and describe the problems you've faced.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
You could as well write a sample of what the text file looks like. What did you do thus far and what don't you understand?

Comment: Store the entire file into some data structure, remove Sarah's info from the data structure, then write the whole data structure back to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting row from text file with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249966/deleting-row-from-text-file-with-python)

Comment: Thanks for you fast help guys. Appreciate your time. Ill go through what you all said and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is small, just re-write the entire file. For text files and built-in functions, this a simple way:

```
with open(filename) as input_file:
    data = []
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.startswith("Sarah,Brown"):
            data.append(line)

with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
    for d in data:
        output_file.write(d + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify a file, you have to overwrite the file completely. Here is a short example:

```
newFile = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        newFile.append(line.strip().split(',')[1:3])

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in newFile:
        f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

Run this with the input file:

```
1,Trevor,H
2,Matt,D
```

The output is:

```
Trevor,H
Matt,D
```